# Chrome OS on HP Mini 1000

Tags: google-chrome-os, hp-mini

I wrote an image of Chrome OS to a USB flash drive and got it to successfully boot.  However, my network adapter is not recognized.  (Neither wifi nor ethernet is working.)

Is there some way to install drivers for it?  Where should I start troubleshooting this?

#### [update]

[Hexxeh](http://chromeos.hexxeh.net/)'s new release (Flow) works just fine on my HP Mini, although I have to hook up to ethernet upon booting the first time.  Good luck!

Comment: I think this is an issue right now, it doesn't work for me on my Acer Aspire One, and this guy made a video for his dell and he has the same issue (http://www.engadget.com/2009/11/24/chrome-os-like-lightning-from-a-usb-key-we-could-get-used-to-th/ ) Think we just have to wait a bit -- but its a cool OS so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the mini 1000 and wifi works with Hexxeh's Cherry version. takes 10 minutess for wifi to work, but it does work.

Comment: Just dled it with rtorrent.  I'll let you know how it turns out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem: HP is not really supportive of Chrome OS. Thus, there is really no good solution. Google is unlikely to add support for this driver. You can try to find a Linux driver and run it from the terminal, though.

Answer (score 0):

hexxeh chromeos

it works off jump drive or sd card on hp mini...mine 1110nr mi edition

ethernet working now but still no joy on wifi

updated today to cherry version which does allow broadcom wifi access